# VB.NET : mysql update query

Tags: mysql, vb.net

My question :
I need to add an UPDATE fonction in my code, only when i have some changes in my DATABASE (from ODBC)
If i have new ID for exemple => i can add it in my MySQL database
and if any name (from NAME fild) change => i can update it in my MySQL database.

```vb
'Read from ODBC and fill data in DataGridView
Public Sub fonction_read_from_odbc()
    connection_to_database()
    Dim da1 As OdbcDataAdapter
    Dim dt1 As DataTable
    da1 = New OdbcDataAdapter("select ID,NAME from DATABASE", conn1)
    dt1 = New DataTable
    da1.Fill(dt1)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt1
    conn1.Close()
    da1.Dispose()
End Sub

'Write data from DataGridView and fill it in MySql DATABASE
Public Sub fonction_write_in_mysql_database() 
    Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=user;database=mydatabase")

    connection.Open()

    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand

    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 Step +1
        cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `mydatabase.mytable` (`ID`, `NAME`) VALUES (@ID,@NAME)", connection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NR", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next

    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

```
    Public Sub fonction_update()
        Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=user;database=mydatabase")
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
            connection.Open()
            cmd = New MySqlCommand("UPDATE mydatabase SET ID = @ID, NAME = @NAME", connection)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


    End Sub
```

[image: description of my problem]

```
The Steps that i used referring to the exemple in the link:
1- connection to ODBC
2- Private odbc_adapter As New OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT..
3- connection to MySQL
4- Private MySQL_adapter As New MySQLDataAdapter("SELECT..
5- Private table As New DataTable
6- fonction : fill data in datagridview => odbc_adapter.Fill(table)
7- fonction : insert_in_mysql As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO ...
8- Dim update_in_mysql As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE...
but the update not working.
```

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miAfg.jpg)
[image: my code]

Comment: Just use the same data adapter as you used to retrieve the data. Call its `Update` method and pass the `DataTable`. That will save the changes in the `DataTable` to the database. That's what a data adapter is for.

Comment: Can you write me the code please (only the update fonction), because I tried several times without success.

Comment: There are lots of examples around of using a data adapter. Read some of them, try to do it and, if it doesn't work, post that code.

Comment: [Here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872)'s one I prepared earlier.

Comment: i try to add a new fonction "fonction_update()" but not working.

Comment: That's not using a data adapter.

Comment: i send photo that explane more my question

Comment: It seems that I misunderstood but the only real difference is that you use two different data adapters. Call `Fill` on one to populate the `DataTable` and then call `Update` on the second to save the data to the second database. The one trick is setting `AcceptChangesOnFill` to `False` on the first data adapter. The link I provided has all the information you need. You just need to pick and choose the parts to combine. There are examples of retrieving data using a data adapter and examples of saving data using a data adapter. You don't need anything else.

Comment: thank you for your help, I tried several times but without effective results.

Comment: Tried what? I see no evidence of an attempt to use two data adapters.

Comment: i send the steps that I have followed

Comment: You have posted a picture of your code, which is something that you should never do, but you are still not making any attempt at all to do what I said. If you refuse to take my advice and use a second data adapter to save the data then please just say that, so i can stop wasting my time trying to get you to do the right thing. I suggest that you see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63374823/convert-data-from-sql-server-to-dbf-file-date-error) for an example. That will be my last contribution unless I see some actual effort to follow my advice.